# While using Google Knowledge Graph API, I am able to get the MID and some basic information. How to get all attributes for a Type as per Schema.org?

Tags: google-knowledge-graph

Able to searchusing

```
ekg.SearchRequest(
        parent=parent,
        query=search_query,
        languages=languages,
        #types=types,
        limit=limit,
    )
response = client.search(request=request)
```

Also able to do a lookup using

```
  request = ekg.LookupRequest(
        parent=parent,
        ids=ids,
        languages=languages,
    )
client.lookup(request=request)
```

These are per the samples listed at https://cloud.google.com/enterprise-knowledge-graph/docs/samples?hl=en.

For sample, I am trying to do a lookup on Organization = Google, with an MID = c-024dcv3mk.
Question: How to do I get all attributes filled as per schema.org Organization schema ?